# Magento2: How to modifiy http header of page?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, 404, http-header

I am trying to modify HTTP header for current URL. I want to set 410 status if current page header is 404.

below code I used but I have created new controller so it always set 410 for that controller but I want to set for current URL.

```
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $resultPage->setStatusHeader(410, '1.1', 'Gone');
    $resultPage->setHeader('Status', '410 Gone');

    return $resultPage;
```

I am not sure which function used to set Http header. Has anyone idea?

Comment: can u explain which url set ?

Comment: @Abdul I added new option 410 in redirect type apart from 301 and 302. Now i want to setup header 410 for those url but its always take 302

Comment: @Kul I have just updated my answer with an example, let me know if you need any more help!

Comment: Hi if check my answere if you are user result redirect then use  extend \Magento\Backend\App\Action



$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

            $resultRedirect->setStatusHeader(403, '1.1', 'Forbidden');

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/auth/login');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implemented in the Mage2 Module Experius PageNotFound which can be found on Github

> https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-PageNotFound

[image]

For more information see the following commit

> https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-PageNotFound/commit/d3332a4f43122f6532617ae57aab8f1d6380a512#diff-6c0df54a0adc7658411e157ba9feaf3a

**additional commit**

> https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-PageNotFound/pull/19/commits/7d230cb6352b16633ed2d32dde28d7527e8eff3a

I recommend to use Mage2Gen to generate your module for you!

**Basic module with Mage2Gen for you!**

> https://mage2gen.com/load/8cfec17a-a5ff-481e-9f36-2091e0237006

Based on this commit you can implement is as followed:

**Add a frontend route - etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="vendor_module" id="vendor_module">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Add a frontend event - etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_cms_noroute_index">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Controller\ActionPredispatch" name="vendor_module_observer_controller_actionpredispatch_controller_action_predispatch"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Create the Observer and implement this function - Observer/Controller/ActionPredispatch.php**

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory 
 */
private $resultFactory;

protected function redirect($url)
{

    if($url=='410'){
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_FORWARD);
        return $result->setModule('experius_pagenotfound')->setController('response')->forward('gone');
    }

}
```

**Then add a Controller - Controller/Response/Gone.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Response;
class Gone extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->setStatusHeader(410, '1.1', 'Gone');
        $resultPage->setHeader('Status', '410 Gone');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Add a Block - Block/Response/Gone.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Response;
class Gone extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->addBodyClass('410');
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set('410 Gone');
        //$this->pageConfig->setKeywords();
        //$this->pageConfig->setDescription();
        $pageMainTitle = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title');
        $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle(__('Whoops, our bad...'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**Update the frontend with layout xml - view/frontend/layout/vendor_module_response_gone.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Response\Gone" name="response.gone" template="Vendor_Module::response/gone.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**And finally add a template - view/frontend/templates/response/gone.phtml**

```
<dl>
    <dt><?php echo __('The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.'); ?></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul class="disc">
            <li><?php echo __('If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.'); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo __('If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.'); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: @mr-lewis I've already use this module. but its redirect to new page and old page url show 302. but i want both url should be 410

Comment: @Kul thanks for your feedback I have just created a fix for this in a pull request https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-PageNotFound/pull/19

Comment: @Kul Changes have been made in the answer in the Observer method | Create the Observer and implement this function - Observer/Controller/ActionPredispatch.php

Comment: @Kul fixes have been merged! And new tag has been added 1.2.5

Comment: Great work @mr.lewis. Its working fine.

Comment: Mr. Lewis any idea if i want to add 410 for any urls. i am not able to get proper event to be called for this observer

Answer (score 1):

I think you first you need to clear header

you can inject this dependency into your __construct

```
   Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Response
```

and then clear header using `clearHeader($name)` method

and then add header by using this code

```
    $header->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine($name, $value);
```

you can find this code sample in this class only

Answer (score 0):

410 != 404

Don't do this. It's a very bad idea.

---

Nevertheless...
You didn't point out what server you are using but I'd use your servers abilities to change the code from 404 to 410. Aka with rewrite conditions.
Consult your server manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this


 /**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
 * Noroute action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setStatusHeader(404, '1.1', 'Not Found');
    $resultPage->setHeader('Status', '404 File not found');
    $resultPage->addHandle('adminhtml_noroute');
    return $resultPage;
}
```